# Converting varchar to decimal with truncate

Tags: sql-server, alter-table, type-conversion, decimal

I have a column called latitude which is currently varchar(20)

I want to convert it to DECIMAL(9,6)

However the data stored inside the column is greater than 6 decimal points
i.e.
48.123456891123456

the table in question has over 50 billion rows and is a 24/7 database with no downtime and uses partitioning by month
(SQL server 2017 enterprise)

How would I achieve the conversion as its too big for 6 decimal points.
I was thinking of creating a copy of the column and renaming when converted, however i'm not sure how i would achieve the truncate to 6 decimal points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind rounding, you can do what you want in one step:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Stringy 
    ALTER COLUMN latitude decimal (9, 6) 
    WITH (ONLINE = ON); -- SQL Server 2016 onward
```

This can be an online operation in SQL Server 2016 or later.

If you need to *truncate* (not round) things are more tricky. You would need to perform a calculation like:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT
    (
        decimal(9,6), 
        ROUND
        (
            CONVERT
            (
                decimal(10, 7), 
                S.latitude
            ), 
            6, -- decimal places
            1  -- truncate, don't round
        )
    )
FROM dbo.Stringy AS S;
```

If there might be some non-numeric values in there, use `TRY_CONVERT` instead and accept nulls in the new column, or provide a default value with `ISNULL`.

If the objective is to save space, you'll need to rebuild the table or run `DBCC CLEANTABLE` (perhaps in small batches until complete) to achieve that. The dropped variable-length string column will continue to take up space until then.